# Как очистить формы input и textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

В чём суть: надо при фокусе на форму, очистить её; если пользователь ничего не ввёл, тогда вернуть исходное значение. С этим я справился.

Появилась другая проблема: если пользователь что-то ввёл, потом сбросил фокус, потом вернулся на форму, атрибут "value" становиться пустым, и так всегда. Код, который за это отвечал:

```
    $(function(){
    $.fn.clearForm = function(){
        $(this).each(function(){
            $(this).data("defValue", $(this).attr("value"));//Запомнить изначальное значение
        })
        .bind("focus", function(){
            if($(this).attr("value") == $(this).data("defValue"))//Если стоит оно
                $(this).attr("value", "").css("color", "black");//Очистить форму и выставить чёрный цвет
        })
        .bind("blur", function(){
            if($(this).attr("value") == "")//Если ничего не ввели
                $(this).attr("value", $(this).data("defValue")).css("color", "grey");//Восстановить изначальное значение
        });
        return $(this);
    };
});
```

Подключил я его вот так:

```
$(function(){$(".clearForm").clearForm();});
```

HTML:

```
<form name = "comment">
                <textarea>Type your comment</textarea>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <input name="comment" class ="clearForm" type = "text" value = "Type your nickname..."><span class="sending">Send</span>
            </form>
```

В таблице стилей, указано только `color:grey` и позиция элемента

После этого, попробовал исправить этот код. Почти получилось. Но, как вы догадались, проблемы остались а конкретно: если пользователь вводит что-то, потом нажимает "Backspace", символ удаляется зрительно, но в "value" всё равно попадает. И осталась та же проблема, пользователь ввёл, сменил фокус с формы, сфокусировался на форме, ничего не ввёл, значение атрибута "value" обнуляется, текст становится серым. HTML не менял, вот код JQuery(подключал точно так же):

```
    $(function(){
    $.fn.clearForm = function(){
        var value = "";//Получает то, что пользователь ввёл
        var tmp = "";//Используется для повторном вводе, когда есть какое-то значение
        $(this).each(function(){
            $(this).data("defValue", $(this).attr("value"));//Запомнить начальное значение
        })
        .bind("focus", function(){
            if($(this).attr("value") == $(this).data("defValue")){//Если сходиться
                $(this).attr("value", "").css("color", "black");//Подготовить форму к написанию текста
            }
         })
        .bind("keypress", function(eventObject){
            value += getChar(eventObject);//Получаем символы с клавиатуры
        }) 
        .bind("blur", function(){ 
            if(($(this).attr("value") == "") && (value == "")){//Если ничего не введено, а поле сброшено
                $(this).attr("value", $(this).data("defValue")).css("color", "grey");//Возвращаемся на исходную
            }else if((value != "") && ($(this).attr("value") == "")){//Если что-то ввели, а поле пустое, тоесть первый ввод текста
                $(this).attr("value", value);
            }else if((value != "") && ($(this).attr("value") != "")){//Если что-то ввели и поле не пустое
                tmp += $(this).attr("value");//Заносим старое значение в tmp
                tmp += value;//добавляем введённое значение
                value = tmp;//присваем основной переменной полное значение
                tmp = "";//Обнуляем tmp
                $(this).attr("value", value);   
            }else if(value == ""){//Мусорная функция, добавил для того, что бы сбрасывать поле ввода
                $(this).attr("value", "");//По задумке, это должно как-то очищать поле ввода, если пользователь жмёт Backspace или выделяет, а потом удаляет текст 
            }
            value = "";//обнуляем
            /*test func*//*ch($(this).attr("value"), 1);*///Этим тестировал
            //Подключал тем же способом
        });
        return $(this);
    };
});
```

Comment: бредок какой-то, если ничего не ввел - очистить, а что очищать если ничего не ввел? дефолтное значение в форме? placeholder подсказку используйте.

Comment: ну как вариант используйте два data() значения.

Comment: Спасибо! Ответ под носом был, а я не видел.

Comment: Сгораю от любопытства, просветите пожалуйста, где же могут понадобиться такие манипуляции?

Comment: Уже нигде. Я про "placeholder" не мог вспомнить и начал такие сложные манипуляции проводить.